# Counting the number of ordered pairs in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, permutation

Given matrix `m` as follows (row-wise permutations of 1-5):

```
    # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 # [1,]    1    5    2    4    3
 # [2,]    2    1    4    3    5
 # [3,]    3    4    1    2    5
 # [4,]    4    1    3    2    5
 # [5,]    4    3    1    2    5
 # [6,]    1    4    2    3    5
 # [7,]    4    3    2    5    1
 # [8,]    4    1    3    5    2
 # [9,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [10,]    4    3    2    1    5
```

I'd like to know the number of times each element 1-5 is preceded another element per row (i.e. considering all possible pairs)

For example, for the pair (1, 5), `1` precedes `5`, 9 times among all rows. Another example, for the pair (3, 1), `3` precedes `1`, 4 times among all rows. I would like to have the same results for all possible pairs among all rows. That is,

```
# (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)
# (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)
# (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5)
# (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5)
# (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4)

m <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L), .Dim = c(10L, 5L))
```

How one can do that efficiently in R?

**EDIT**

How would you do the same for this matrix?

```
      # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 # [1,]    3    4    1    5    0
 # [2,]    1    2    5    3    0
 # [3,]    3    5    0    0    0
 # [4,]    4    5    0    0    0
 # [5,]    3    4    1    5    2
 # [6,]    3    1    2    0    0
 # [7,]    4    1    5    2    0
 # [8,]    4    3    5    2    0
 # [9,]    5    2    0    0    0
# [10,]    5    4    2    0    0

m <- structure(c(3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 1, 1, 
3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 5, 0, 2, 5, 3, 0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 5L))
```

Comment: Does `m`, really, contain permutations? I.e., in each row, each number appears only once (apart from 0)? How large is your actual `m`?

Comment: @alexis_laz yes, each number appears only once per row. `m` could be of size 1000-10000 or so with 2-10 or so for number of columns.

Comment: Also, are the 0's, always, clustered at the end of each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that (1) each row does not have duplicates, (2) each row's 0's are clustered at the end and, (3) `nrow(m)` is 2-3 orders of magnitude larger than `ncol(m)`, we can loop over the columns searching for the appearance of a specific number reducing unnecessary computations when 0's are reached:

```
ff = function(x, a, b)
{
    ia = rep_len(NA_integer_, nrow(x)) # positions of 'a' in each row
    ib = rep_len(NA_integer_, nrow(x)) # -//- of 'b'
    notfound0 = seq_len(nrow(x))  # rows that have not, yet, a 0
    for(j in seq_len(ncol(x))) {
        xj = x[notfound0, j]
        if(!length(xj)) break

        ia[notfound0[xj == a]] = j
        ib[notfound0[xj == b]] = j

        notfound0 = notfound0[xj != 0L]  # check if any more rows have 0 now on
    }

    i = ia < ib ## is 'a' before 'b'?

    ## return both a - b and b - a; no need to repeat computations
    data.frame(a = c(a, b), 
               b = c(b, a), 
               n = c(sum(i, na.rm = TRUE), sum(!i, na.rm = TRUE)))
}
```

And on the editted `m`:

```
ff(m, 3, 2)
# a b n
#1 3 2 3
#2 2 3 1
ff(m, 5, 1)
#  a b n
#1 5 1 0
#2 1 5 4
```

And for all pairs:

```
xtabs(n ~ a + b, 
      do.call(rbind, 
              combn(5, 2, function(x) ff(m, x[1], x[2]), 
                    simplify = FALSE)))
#   b
#a   1 2 3 4 5
#  1 0 4 1 0 4
#  2 0 0 1 0 1
#  3 3 3 0 2 4
#  4 3 4 1 0 5
#  5 0 5 1 1 0
```

And, also it seems tolerable on a larger scale:

```
set.seed(007)
MAT = do.call(rbind, combinat::permn(8))[sample(1e4), ]
MAT[sample(length(MAT), length(MAT)*0.4)] = 0L #40% 0s
MAT = t(apply(MAT, 1, function(x) c(x[x != 0L], rep_len(0L, sum(x == 0L)))))
dim(MAT)
#[1] 10000     8

## including colonel's answer for a quick comparison
colonel = function(x, a, b)
{
    i = (which(!t(x - b)) - which(!t(x - a))) > 0L
    data.frame(a = c(a, b), b = c(b, a), n = c(sum(i), sum(!i)))
} 

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(ff(MAT, 7, 2), colonel(MAT, 7, 2))
#Unit: milliseconds
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
#      ff(MAT, 7, 2) 3.795003 3.908802 4.500453 3.972138 4.096377 45.926679   100   b
# colonel(MAT, 7, 2) 2.156941 2.231587 2.423053 2.295794 2.404894  3.775516   100  a 
#There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

So, just a simple translation of the approach into a loop proved to be efficient enough. More 0s should, also, decrease computational time further.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a vectorized solution, without `apply`:

```
func <- function(a,b) sum((which(!t(m-b)) - which(!t(m-a)))>0)

#> func(1,5)
#[1] 9
#> func(5,1)
#[1] 1
```

And to generate all the wanted combinations you can simply do:

```
N = combn(1:5, 2)
cbind(N, N[nrow(N):1,])
```

You then need only one loop to iterate over columns and apply the function.

Answer (score 3):

First, how we can do it with hard-coded numbers:

```
apply(m, 1, function(r) { which(r == 1) < which(r == 5) })
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
sum(apply(m, 1, function(r) { which(r == 1) < which(r == 5) }))
# [1] 9
```

To automate this for all combinations of `1:5` (except same), here's a data.frame with all pairs:

```
df <- expand.grid(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
df <- df[ df$a != df$b, ]
head(df)
#   a b
# 2 2 1
# 3 3 1
# 4 4 1
# 5 5 1
# 6 1 2
# 8 3 2
```

Now we just need to iterate on each row of this (I guess we could have used a matrix with another `apply`):

```
df$seqs <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) {
  sum(apply(m, 1, function(r) which(r == df$a[i]) < which(r == df$b[i])))
})
head(df)
#   a b seqs
# 2 2 1    3
# 3 3 1    4
# 4 4 1    6
# 5 5 1    1
# 6 1 2    7
# 8 3 2    6
```

Alternatively, I think this is a great time to use `mapply`:

```
myfunc <- function(a, b, m) sum(apply(m, 1, function(r) which(r == a) < which(r == b)))
df$seqs <- mapply(myfunc, df$a, df$b, list(m))
head(df)
#   a b seqs
# 2 2 1    3
# 3 3 1    4
# 4 4 1    6
# 5 5 1    1
# 6 1 2    7
# 8 3 2    6
```

Granted, I used a formal function vice an anonymous one (could have done that above, too), but this shows off some elegance of this method.

**Edit**: new constraints, now there may be no-matches in `m`. The above fails since `which` returns `logical(0)` when there are no matches, causing `sapply` to return a heterogenous list. One way to fix it is with a quick helper function:

```
apply(m, 1, function(r) which(r == a) < which(r == b))
# [[1]]
# logical(0)
# [[2]]
# [1] FALSE
# ...

emptyF <- function(x) sapply(x, function(y) if (! length(y)) FALSE else y)
emptyF(apply(m, 1, function(r) which(r == a) < which(r == b)))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now `myfunc` becomes:

```
myfunc <- function(a, b, m) sum(emptyF(apply(m, 1, function(r) which(r == a) < which(r == b))))
```

(Note: I prefer [Colonel Beauvel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242888/3358272) in that it's vectorized and therefore likely much faster. It would also benefit from this and similar remedies to no-matches.))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library(plyr)
combns <- expand.grid(unique(as.vector(m)),unique(as.vector(m)))
combns <- combns[combns$Var1!=combns$Var2,]
combns <- combns[with(combns,order(Var1)),]
combns$count <- sapply(1:nrow(combns),function(u) sum(unlist(apply(apply(m,1,function(t) match(t,combns[u,])),2,function(s) na.exclude(count(unlist(sapply(seq(length(s)),function(t) diff(s,lag=t))))$freq[count(unlist(sapply(seq(length(s)),function(t) diff(s,lag=t))))$x==1]))),na.rm = T))
```